# Thinking about domain validation

Tags: php, function, validation, url, dns

this is my first question. And btw I am unconfy with RegExes.

I was thinking about a PHP function that validates domains or URLs, given by user input. (Sub)Domains shall be collected via html input field.
So I have to deal with different formats like `http(s)://domain.tld` and `domain.tld` both with the possibility of including a path or being invalid.

The function should rather correct almost correct user input instead of returning false.

In the end, I want to return the format `(sub.)domain.tld`, but only for real existing domains.

My WIP-solution is the following. What do you think about it?

```
function valDomain($url,$prefix=""){
    $url = trim($url);
    $url = str_replace(" ", "", $url);
    $url = trim($url,'.');
    $url = trim($url,'?');
    $url = trim($url,'-');
    $url = trim($url,'/');
    $url = strtolower($url);
    $url = substr($url,0,100);

    if(strpos($url,'.') == false) {
        return false;
    }

    if(strpos($url,'http') !== false) {
        $x = parse_url($url);
        if(isset($x['host'])){
            $url = $x['host'];
        }
    }
    if(strpos($url,'/') !== false) {
        $x = explode("/", $url);
        if(isset($x[0])){
            $url = $x[0];
        }
    }

    if(checkdnsrr($url,"A")){
        return $prefix.$url;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For explanation: It tidies up the user input, checks if it can be a url/domain at all, takes the host if it's a proper url, deletes the path, and then, when it only should be the raw url, check if there is a dns entry corresponding to it. Only if yes, it returns the validated domain. Other it returns false.

Does this make sense?

(The `$prefix` argument can optionally be used to add a `http://` to the url in order to render a hyperlink).
Retrieved results will be stored in database, so they need to be hack-safe.

Comment: Have you considered [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with the [`FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) filter type? If so, why doesn't that meet your needs?

Comment: `should rather correct almost correct user input` how do you know what the correct URL would be?

Comment: @chris85 the user might not understand the difference between `domain.tld` and `domain.tld/`. Those kinds of "almost invalid" inputs shall be corrected

Comment: Oh, with the URL below `(sub.)domain.tld` I thought you were to know `sub` should be the subdomain.